# Why can a slice be changed in functions by assigning, but not in a for loop?

Tags: loops, pointers, go, slice

I need every score to be changed to some other values here in the function which receives the pointer of a slice, I can change the values by assigning but nothing changed if I do it in a for loop. Why is that?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type TestType struct {
    id    int
    score float64
}

func worker(index int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, listScores *[][]TestType) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

    // It works by assigning.
    (*listScores)[index] = []TestType{{index + 1, 2.22},
        {index + 1, 2.22},
        {index + 1, 2.22},}
    // It doesn't work in a for loop.
    //for _, score := range (*listScores)[index] {
    //  score.score = 2.22
    //}
}

func main() {
    scoresList := [][]TestType{
        {{1, 0.0},
            {1, 0.0},
            {1, 0.0},},
        {{2, 0.0},
            {2, 0.0},
            {2, 0.0},
        },}

    fmt.Println(scoresList)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i, _ := range scoresList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(i, &wg, &scoresList)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(scoresList)
}
```

Scores can be changed to 2.22 by assigning a new whole slice to it:

```
[[{1 0} {1 0} {1 0}] [{2 0} {2 0} {2 0}]]
[[{1 2.22} {1 2.22} {1 2.22}] [{2 2.22} {2 2.22} {2 2.22}]]
```

But if I do it in a for loop as in the comment, the output is like this:

```
[[{1 0} {1 0} {1 0}] [{2 0} {2 0} {2 0}]]
[[{1 0} {1 0} {1 0}] [{2 0} {2 0} {2 0}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `range` give you two element:

- the index
- a **copy** of the element if you iterate a slice.

The code can be changed to the following one without use the thread:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testType struct {
    id    int
    score float64
}

func main() {
    scoresList := [][]testType{
        {{1, 0.0}, {1, 0.0}, {1, 0.0}},
        {{2, 0.0}, {2, 0.0}, {2, 0.0}}}
    fmt.Println(scoresList)
    for i := range scoresList {
        scoresList[i] = []testType{{i + 1, 2.22},
            {i + 1, 2.22},
            {i + 1, 2.22}}
    }
    fmt.Println(scoresList)
}
```

If you want to use the thread, than you can use the following one:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type TestType struct {
    id    int
    score float64
}

func worker(index int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, listScores *[][]TestType) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

    for i := range (*listScores)[index] {
        (*listScores)[index][i].score = 2.22
    }
}

func main() {
    scoresList := [][]TestType{
        {{1, 0.0},
            {1, 0.0},
            {1, 0.0}},
        {{2, 0.0},
            {2, 0.0},
            {2, 0.0},
        }}

    fmt.Println(scoresList)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i, _ := range scoresList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(i, &wg, &scoresList)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(scoresList)
}
```